# I need help on this differential equaion problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value, vectors

Let equation $(1)$ be $\overrightarrow{F}= m \cdot \overrightarrow{a}$ and equation $(2)$ be $\overrightarrow{F}= \frac{-G \cdot M \cdot m}{  |    \overrightarrow{r^2} |}  \frac{\overrightarrow{r}  }{  | \overrightarrow{r}  |}$.

The problem says to equate both force equations and cancel the common factor which I get

$a = \frac{-GM}{|r|^2 }\frac{ r}{|r|}$ where $r$ is a vector.

The problem I'm having that the next question asks me to use the fact that $a(t)= r"(t)$, and $r(t)= x(t)i+y(t)j$ and convert the equation I found into an equation invovling $x(t)$ and $y(t)$.

I don't know how to do this. Also, I don't know how to deal with the absolute values and vectors. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $\vec{r} = x\hat{i} + y\hat{j}$. Therefore, $\vec{r}^{\prime\prime} = 
x^{\prime\prime}\hat{i} + y^{\prime\prime}\hat{j}$ and $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. Therefore, the equation
\begin{equation}
\vec{a} = -\frac{GM}{|r|^3}\vec{r}
\end{equation}
gives two scalar equations
\begin{equation}
x^{\prime\prime} = -\frac{GM}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}x 
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
y^{\prime\prime} = -\frac{GM}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}y 
\end{equation}
In practice, it is convenient to use polar coordinates to solve this problem.

Comment: Shouldn;t it be \begin{equation}
x^{\prime\prime} = -\frac{GM}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}x 
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
y^{\prime\prime} =- \frac{GM}{(x^2 + y^2)^{3/2}}y 
\end{equation} ?

Comment: @Mary. You are right. I missed the negative sign. Let me edit it now. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a(t)=r''(t)$, replacing it at the equation $a = \frac{-GM}{|r|^2 }\frac{ r}{|r|}$, we get:
$$r''(t) = \frac{-GM}{|r(t)|^2 }\frac{ r(t)}{|r(t)|}$$
$$r(t)=x(t)i+y(t)j \Rightarrow |r(t)|=\sqrt{x^2(t)+y^2(t)}$$
$$r''(t)=x''(t)i+y''(t)j$$
$$\text{So } x''(t)i+y''(t)j=\frac{-GM}{\sqrt{x^2(t)+y^2(t)}^2 }\frac{ x(t)i+y(t)j}{\sqrt{x^2(t)+y^2(t)}}=\frac{-GM(x(t)i+y(t)j)}{({x^2(t)+y^2(t))}^{\frac{3}{2} }}$$